# If/ else if statements to show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some *if* and *else if* statements to *show* and *hide* svg elements and it works the way it should but I wonder if I can shorten the code since it looks so repetitive.

I'm not sure if it's possible since I'm not a JS/JQuery expert.

**If/else if code**

```
        //Door type 1
        if( id2 == "#Door1" && id3 == "#Grey")
        {
            var door = "#Door1Grey"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG)").hide();
            //console.log($("g" + door).show().siblings());
        }
        else if( id2 == "#Door1" && id3 == "#Blue")
        {
            var door = "#Door1Blue"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }
        else if( id2 == "#Door1" && id3 == "#Red")
        {
            var door = "#Door1Red"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }

        //Door type 2
        else if( id2 == "#Door2" && id3 == "#Grey")
        {
            var door = "#Door2Grey"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }
        else if( id2 == "#Door2" && id3 == "#Blue")
        {
            var door = "#Door2Blue"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }
        else if( id2 == "#Door2" && id3 == "#Red")
        {
            var door = "#Door2Red"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }

        //Door type 3
        else if( id2 == "#Door3" && id3 == "#Grey")
        {
            var door = "#Door3Grey"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }
        else if( id2 == "#Door3" && id3 == "#Blue")
        {
            var door = "#Door3Blue"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }
        else if( id2 == "#Door3" && id3 == "#Red")
        {
            var door = "#Door3Red"
            $("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
            //console.log(door);
        }
```

**id, id2 and id3 are set here:**

```
        var wallChoice = String($('input[name=radiosWall]:checked', '#myFormFront').val());
        var id = String("#" + wallChoice);
        $("g" + id).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();

        var doorChoice = String($('input[name=radiosDoor]:checked', '#myFormFront').val());
        var id2 = String("#" + doorChoice);

        var doorColorChoice = String($('input[name=radiosColor]:checked', '#myFormFront').val());
        var id3 = String("#" + doorColorChoice);
```

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should've added it or not, I changed it now.

Comment: Please show us your SVG as well. You could make a live demo by pressing Ctrl-M in the question editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it is a bit repetitive. I believe you could boil it down to the following:

```
var door = id2 + id3.substr(1);
$("g" + door).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
```

or even:

```
$("g" + id2 + id3.substr(1)).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
```

**ALSO** if you change:

```
var doorColorChoice = String($('input[name=radiosColor]:checked', '#myFormFront').val());
var id3 = String("#" + doorColorChoice);
```

to

```
var id3 = String($('input[name=radiosColor]:checked', '#myFormFront').val());
```

you could have:

```
$("g" + id2 + id3).show().siblings("g:not(#BG," + id + ")").hide();
```

(provided the rest of your code doesn't need the "#" (hash) in `id3`. That would be faster than using `substr`)

Comment: Happy to help :)